# SQL Server- reporting services failed to open in IE after patching

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql, ssrs

I have SQL 2005 server - 32 bit standard edition. The server has SSAS,SSIS,SSRS and database services.
I patched the server to 9.00.4220.

We are having problems with reporting services. It starts fine and connects to database (as from activity monitor) but the resportserver page doesnt open in IE.
It says:

HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found.
Internet Information Services (IIS)

When connection from management studio it says:

the attempt to connect to the report server failed. check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version

What should I do?

Regards
Manjot

Comment: also, the initialisation tick is greyed out  after patching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some troubleshooting steps:

- Are you seeing any errors in the Application event log for the OS?
- Do you see the hits against /reportserver/ in the IIS logs?
- Have you verified in IIS that the /reportserver/ virtual directory is still present and that it's using the correct application pool (which has the proper identity)?

Comment: Application event log has following error: 

.NET Runtime Optimization Service (clr_optimization_v2.0.50727_32) - Failed to compile: Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91 . Error code = 0x80070002 

How to check IIS logs? 

Yes the files are still present 

Files in ReportServer directory are: 

rsreportserver.config 

web.config and others 

Files in Reports directory are: 

RSwebappplication.config

 Web.config and others